# Ember.js controller needs and child controller

Tags: ember.js

I'm having trouble targeting a child controller from the parent controller.

Having this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="parent">
    <h1>Parent controller</h1>
    {{control "child"}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="child">
    <h2>Child controller</h2>
    {{controller}}
</script>

App.ParentController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ["child"],
    applyActionOnChild:function(){
        this.get('controllers.child').someAction();
    }
});
App.ParentView = Ember.View.extend({});

App.ChildController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    someAction:function(){
        //Called but not the right instance
    };
});
App.ChildView = Ember.View.extend({});
```

The needs feature of ember seems to work when a child controller calls the parent controller but not for the other way around...

If I place a breakpoint in the someAction method, I can see I have a different object reference than the one displayed on the child view...

Anyone knows how this could work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you specify `{{controller "child"}}`, did you mean `{{control "child"}}`? If not hard to tell what you're trying to do.

The needs feature is for wiring together controller singletons, but The control helper renders template in context of a new controller/view pair. You can't use needs to access these controllers, since there'd be no way for needs to know which instance you meant.

Sounds like instead you want to render "child" template in context of the one true `childController` singleton. In that case use the render helper: `{{render "child"}}`

Comment: Cool, glad that helps. FWIW the `{{control}}` helper is still experimental, if it gets rolled into public API official docs will follow. Meantime @darthdeus has a good blog post on the various helpers here: http://darthdeus.github.com/blog/2013/02/10/render-control-partial-view/